# What is the difference between cross validation and model selection in sklearn?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, python, model-selection, scikit-learn

I would appreciate if someone explains the difference in a very simple manner as I am a beginner in python and Machine Learning.

Comment: They aren't quite the same idea, which makes this rather broad & unclear. In addition, questions about software are generally off topic here, unless there is a clear machine learning motivation. Moreover, the gist of both topics has already been covered on the site, so searching & reading around should provide what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Cross validation is just one of the methods for model selection http://scikit-learn.org/stable/model_selection.html. I would read on topics of model selection: cross validation, feature selection and evaluation. I am sorry for this general answer, but the topic is just too broad.

As a starting point I would suggest Machine Learning by Thom Mitchell. Event if it was pusblished in 1998, many topics are still relevant and nicely introduced. Concretely model selection and evaluation.

A more in depth book is [Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20Sixth%20Printing.pdf), which is freely available.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is that cross validation, along with bootstrapping, is one of the two major re-sampling methods used to decide which model out of your model universe will be best at predicting on new data.

The typical model selection process is train/test. Test data is put aside for one look after model selection for deciding on model accuracy. The training data is used repeatedly to create numerous models. One wants to pick the model that is best at prediction.   There is the issue of which class of model to chose, and within a given class of models, which hyper parameters to chose. How does decide which model and set of hyper parameters  is best for prediction ?  Just using the loss function which was used to pick the 'best' models not only will give one overly optimistic estimates of model accuracy, but it smacks solidly of over-fitting.  The model that fits the data best may not predict the best. For example a linear regression on a full set of variables will always fit the data best, but will usually under perform best subset et. al at prediction.  The standard approach to picking a 'best' model is to use either bootstrapping or one of the many flavors of cross validation to resample the data. 
I personally find the that caret, the R equivalent of scikit-learn has much better documentation than scikit-learn. In particular googling "trainControl caret" will give you at least a couple of articles written by Max Kuhn, the package author.  I think these articles explain clearly and in detail what is going on with resampling and model selection.